# Disable access to all Identity pages in .NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Is there a clean way to completely prevent access to all pages in the `/Areas/Identity`/ folder that gets created when you install .NET Identity?  I was hoping there would be something I could do in `startup.cs`.

I tried creating a filter inheriting from `ActionFilter`:

```
public class PreventAccessToIdentityFolderFilter : IActionFilter
{

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.Path.HasValue && request.Path.Value.ToLower().StartsWith("/identity"))
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/");
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then registering it both in MVC and Razor Pages (since the new Identity UI uses Razor Pages):

```
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMvcOptions(o => {
        o.Filters.Add(new PreventAccessToIdentityFolderFilter());
    });

var mvcBuilder = services.AddControllersWithViews(o => {

    var policy = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    o.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter(policy));

    o.Filters.Add(new PreventAccessToIdentityFolderFilter());
});
```

The filter run on all MVC actions, but does not run for any of the Identity Razor Pages.

There must be an easy way to completely disable access to the `/Identity` Area / Razor Pages?

Answer (score 1):

Need 2 actions:

1. Delete folder `Areas` and all things inside it by Visual Studio.
2. Remove NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI`

Answer (score 1):

If you want some users to access these pages, you can block a path based on an autorization policy.

```cs
    services.AddRazorPages(options => {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Path", "policy name");
    });
    services.AddAuthorization(options => {
        options.AddPolicy("policy name", policy => ... );
    });
```